# Tex document that displays its own source code

Tags: macros, tex-core

Just out of curiosity, I was wondering how it is possible to write a LaTeX document which, when compiled, generates a document that contains exactly its own source code (i. e. a [*quine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29)).

Since LaTeX is Turing-complete, there's an argument from theoretical computer science which ensures the existence of such a document, but it seems rather hard to actually construct such a program.

I hope that someone is able to come up with a nice solution to this brainteaser.

Comment: Sorry, stackexchange doesn't seem to have a way to cancel my vote, but please consider the my reopen vote cancelled.